# Javascript Array remove element when price is lower than X

Tags: javascript

I want to delete items from my array *where the price is **lower than 20***

This is my array:

```
[
  {
    "suggested_price": 50,
    "suggested_price_floor": 0,
    "name": "Itemname",
    "image": "link",
    "wear": null,
    "color": "ffbb00",
    "id": 6039365
  },
  {
    "suggested_price": 50,
    "suggested_price_floor": 0,
    "name": "Itemname",
    "image": "link",
    "wear": null,
    "color": "ffbb00",
    "id": 6039365
  }
]
```

and if the `suggested_price` is lower than 20, i will delete that out of my array list

I tried to find how on the internet but couldn't find how :/
Only find sorting array by price

Comment: Filter first, then reduce?

Comment: Sounds like `filter` only

Comment: @CertainPerformance I thought I read the OP wanted to add them up, but no.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const items = [{
    suggested_price: 19,
    suggested_price_floor: 0,
    name: 'Itemname',
    image: 'link',
    wear: null,
    color: 'ffbb00',
    id: 6039365
  },
  {
    suggested_price: 50,
    suggested_price_floor: 0,
    name: 'Itemname',
    image: 'link',
    wear: null,
    color: 'ffbb00',
    id: 6039365
  }
];

const reducedItems = items.filter(item => (item.suggested_price > 20));
console.log(reducedItems)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which will create a new array with the condition passed on the filter function

```js
var res = [
  {
    "suggested_price": 50,
    "suggested_price_floor": 0,
    "name": "Itemname",
    "image": "link",
    "wear": null,
    "color": "ffbb00",
    "id": 6039365
  },
  {
    "suggested_price": 6,
    "suggested_price_floor": 0,
    "name": "Itemname",
    "image": "link",
    "wear": null,
    "color": "ffbb00",
    "id": 6039365
  },
{
    "suggested_price": 15,
    "suggested_price_floor": 0,
    "name": "Itemname",
    "image": "link",
    "wear": null,
    "color": "ffbb00",
    "id": 6039365
  },
{
    "suggested_price": 34,
    "suggested_price_floor": 0,
    "name": "Itemname",
    "image": "link",
    "wear": null,
    "color": "ffbb00",
    "id": 6039365
  }
]

// instead of 30 you can replace with your value
let filteredArray = res.filter(o => o.suggested_price > 30)

console.log("filtered Array greater than 30", filteredArray)

// addition if you want to  reduce the array , you can do the below

let totalOfSuggPrice = filteredArray.reduce((a,c) => ({total: a.suggested_price + c.suggested_price}))

console.log("sum of the filtered array - total of the suggested price",totalOfSuggPrice )
```